# To go off of something meaning

Tags: phrasal-verbs, idiomatic-language

I hear this a lot especially in group discussions when someone says, "Going off of [an earlier comment],[I want to say that]..." I've also heard "I want to bounce off of [another person's point and say that]..." I can't find this in the dictionary, obviously, as I presume it's relatively an emerging phrase. I assume it means that the speaker is agreeing with what the last one said and wants to add a different point on the same issue. Am I correct? How would you define this? Are there any other phrasal verbs or idiomatic phrases that mean the same thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. I have seen 'going off of the last sentence, an earlier thread, earlier comment' many times. It means let's pick up from the last sentence and let's continue the discussion.